# Mouse resize table column

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

In windows applications we often see tabular data that is visible in a single row.  Columns have some max width and the rest of the text is truncated.  Said text can be made visible with a click and drag of the mouse on said column.

Can this behavior be emulated in web via JavaScript/jQuery or (less preferable) devexpress?

In other words how can I expand something like...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>column data</td>
<td>column 2 data lots of text where this text does not fit on screen and is truncated</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Depending on your needs, you could always emulate this fairly easily with a little CSS and jQuery as well. `td {max-width: 50px; max-height: 12px; overflow: hidden; }` `$(td).dblclick(function(e) { $(e.currentTarget).css('max-width', 'none' });`

Comment: @HerroRygar - Neat idea, but things get tricky when more than 1 row is involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look on [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/) jQuery plugin :

Here is a demo : http://www.flexigrid.info/sample.html